# Using Jquery $this for Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, this

I'm creating a dropdown menu that toggles the dropdown when the parent element is clicked. However, currently, all of the dropdown menus open when an item is clicked. I know I need to use $this, but I can't figure out where to apply it.

Here is the current code:

```
// When the parent element is clicked...
jQuery('#menu-main li.has-dropdown a').click(function() {

     // The dropdown will toggle open/close
     jQuery('#top-bar-wrapper .top-bar.expanded .top-bar-section .dropdown').toggle();
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="top-bar-wrapper">
    <nav class="top-bar expanded">  
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul id="menu-main">
                <li><a href="#">No Dropdown</a></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown Menu</a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">No Dropdown 2</a></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown Menu 2</a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Three</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the HTML you provided, the following will work:

```
$('#menu-main li.has-dropdown > a').off('click').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').next('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yadbwLgr/)

The key is to get the context of the clicked element by using `$(this)`. The above snippet will toggle the visibility of the clicked element's parent's next sibling with class `dropdown`.